# How can you log all Mongo write commands?

Tags: meteor

Out of CRUD, I'm just interested in logging CUD, but a solution that just logged all queries including reads would be fine as well.

Comment: I would read up on OPLOG and what can I do with it. Or you could add a line of code after your inserts, updates or whatever you re interested in, and register the operation in separate collection.

Comment: OPLOG individualizes updates – I'd like the original query. Could do after each query, but there are a lot. Would be nice if way to instrument the driver or something.

Comment: Are you after the amount of operation done of certain type, like inserts, updates. Or you d like to know what fields the operation involves etc. Elaborate a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the oplog (which is a bit burdensome). A nice way to do it would be to use the `matb33:collection-hooks` package:

Once you add it in using `meteor add matb33:collection-hooks`. You can 'hook onto a collection and log updates:

```
var test = new Mongo.Collection("test");

test.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
    console.log("Inserting", doc, "into 'test' by", userId)
});
```

The oplog could get everything as a `catch-all`. You would have to parse each oplog change, though.

Another option would be to use a collection [observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes).